# Nullablle support in Scala

Tags: scala, gson, nullable

Can I have Nullable parameters in Scala object.

Similar to Nullable in C# and the syntactic sugar:

```
public int? Age {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public bool? isAdmin {get; set;}
```

Can I create scala class where the object can have some of these attributes set while others not?

I intend to have multiple constructors for different purposes. I want to ensure a null value implies the field is not set.

**UPDATE**

for example I have the following case class

```
case class Employee(age: Int, salary: Int, scaleNum : Int,
                            name: String, memberId: Int )
```

I am using GSON to serialize the class in JSON.

In some cases however, I don't want to pass values for some of the parameters such that the GSON serializer will only include the parameters that have non-NULL value.

How can I achieve that with Options or otherwise?

Comment: _nullable_ = [**Option**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks. I'm new to scala so could you please elaborate more? Can I have all the values in constructor as option? except one perhaps... an example if possible would be appreciated.

Comment: Any field that can be _nullable_ in Scala should be modelled using **Option**, Scala code does not have `null`, only exception is when interacting with freaking Java. - As the name suggests an **Option** represents that such value may or may not exists and you have to deal with that. If you are new to Scala I would recommedn you to read some book or take some course, Scala is not another OOP language like C# is a mix between OOP and FP, learning the language is more than learning syntax, you have to learn a new way to model and solve problems.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for that insight. I am using Scala because I'm using Gatling for testing, no offense but wasn't my first choice... I updated my question with specific asks so it is clear. I doubt I have time to read book about Scala at this point. Do you have concrete answer on how to achieve what I am asking please?

Comment: Make all the fields that can be `null` an **Option** and make their default value a `None` _(e.g. `age: Int = None`)_, that way you only need to pass the values you want _(wrapped in a some, e.g. `Employee(age = Some(35))`)_ - and use a **Scala** library for the json part _(for example [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/))_ instead of a **Java** library like GSON.

Comment: GSON is an interesting choice here. It is a Java library that is not aware of Scala Options by default. You might want to look into `circe` or something else that is able cast missing fields to `None` by default and visa versa. So you can just do `dropNullKeys = true`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common declaration in Scala for your example would be:

```scala
case class Employee(
   age: Option[Int], // For int? Age 
   name: String // For string Name
   // your other decls ...
)
```

Then you can use the type easily:

```scala
val john = Employee( age = Some(10), name = "John" )
```

While Scala 2 allows null values for references types (like String, etc) it is slowly changing starting with Scala 3 (https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/explicit-nulls.html).

### JSON support

Java libraries (like GSON) don't know anything about Scala, so you should consider using other libraries for JSON support that support Scala:

- circe
- play json
- jsoniter-scala
- uPickle
- etc

Those libraries not just aware of `Option[]` in your class definitions, but also have improved support for Scala collections, implicits, default values and other Scala language features.

It is really important to choose an appropriate library for this, because with the Java JSON libs you will end up with Java-style classes and code, compatibility issues with other Scala libs.

With the Circe your example would be:

```scala
import io.circe._
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.parser._
import io.circe.generic.auto._

val john = Employee( age = Some(10), name = "John" )
val johnAsJson = john.asJson.dropNullValues

decode[Employee]( johnAsJson ) match {
   case Right(johnBack) => ??? // johnBack now is the same as john
   case Left(err) => ??? // handle JSON parse exceptions
}
```

---

### Null coalescing operator

Now you might be looking where is the Null Coalescing Operator (`??` in C#, `?` in Kotlin, ...) in Scala.

The direct answer - there is none in the language itself. In Scala we work with Option (and other monadic structures, or ADT) in FP way.

That means, for example:

```scala
case class Address(zip : Option[String])

case class Employee(
   address: Option[Address]
)

val john = Employee( address = Some( Address( zip = Some("1111A") )) )
```

you *should avoid* this style:

```scala
if (john.address.isDefined) {
  if(john.address.zip.isDefined) {
    ...
  }
}
```

you can use `map`/`flatMap`s instead:

```scala
john.address.flatMap { address =>
  address.zip.map { zip =>
     // your zip and address value
    ??
  }
}
    
// or if you need only zip in a short form:

john.address.flatMap(_.zip).map { zip =>
  // your zip value
  ??
}
```

or `for-comprehension` syntax (which is based on the same flatMaps):

```scala
for {
  address <- john.address
  zip <- address.zip
}
yield {
 // doing something with zip and address
 ??
}
```

The important part is that idiomatic way to solve this in Scala mostly based on patterns from FP.